# Refreshing left navigation bar after clicking on the main navigation bar (top horizontal) in asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I'm creating a menu navigation bar (main menu) which all submenus will be located at the left side. Since the main menu bar were called/build-up inside the _Layout.cshtml, how can i rebuild/refresh the submenus if it will be resided on the _Layout.cshtml and also on every click action of the main item(s)?

```
     <div>
        @{ Html.RenderAction("Menu", "Home"); }
    </div>
    <div class="leftmenu">
       @{ Html.RenderAction("SubMenu", "Home"); }
    </div>
```

Hoping for your kind response. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you have both menus in the _Layout.cshtml file. The main menu is fixed, and the left menu depends on every specific page (but it's also fixed, per page).

In that case, my approach would be to create a section in the _Layout.cshtml file, called i.e. "SubMenu", where each page would be able to define it's sub menu items.

_Layout.cshtml page

```
@RenderSection("SubMenu", required: false)
```

_SpecificPageView.cshtml

```html
@section SubMenu {
  <div class="leftmenu">
     @{ Html.RenderAction("SubMenu", "Home"); }
  </div>
}
```

Comment: Yes. The top menu is fixed and the left menu items depends on the selected action/item on the main menu. The submenus is based on query results (records from database) so submenus is dynamic.

Thank you for your help.